# Python only writes one lot of data to file

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

The script is a web scraper that takes emails from trust a trader - I need it to write to a text file as well as printing to the console. Here is the code, why is it only printing one "batch" of data from a url to the file?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
urls = ['http://www.trustatrader.com/search/?seed=&trade=1&where=Avon&page=1','http://www.trustatrader.com/search/?seed=&trade=1&where=Bedfordshire&page=1']
myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'a')
for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    emails = tree.xpath('//li[@class="email"]/a/@href')
    emails = [email.replace('mailto:','') for email in emails]
    emails = [email.replace(' ','') for email in emails]
    for email in emails:
        print str(email)+';'
        myfile.write("%s\n" % email)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Check your indentation, it works for me.

Comment: What alecxe said -- Stackoverflow automagically converts tabs to spaces, so double check that you don't have any tabs in the code.

Comment: Yeah i had tabs in the code which was causing the issue, thank you!